# Add columns to an existing SQL database in R

Tags: r, sqldf, r-dbi

I'm trying to create an `SQL` database from a set of `data.frame`s in `R`. These `data.frame`s have the same row names but different columns. In the `SQL` database I would therefore like them all to be in the same table, where `data.frame`1 with n1 columns will populate 1:n1 columns in this `SQL` table, `data.frame`2 with n2 columns will populate (n1+1):n2 columns in this `SQL` table, and so on.

For writing the first `data.frame` (`df1` below) to the `SQL` database table, my code is:

```
library(sqldf)
setwd(db_path)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=db_name)
dbWriteTable(db, table_id, as.data.frame(df1))
```

Where `db_path` is the path to the SQL database, `db_name` is the name, `table_id` is the table's name, and `df1` is the first `data.frame`.

Obviously, I can `cbind` these `data.frame`s and then just `dbWriteTable` that combined `data.frame`. Or, for every `data.frame` I want to add use `dbGetQuery` to fetch the `table_id`, `cbind` the new `data.frame` to that and then write that back to `db`. My `data.frame`s, however, are quite large, and therefore I was wondering if there's any operation that avoids holding all of them in memory before writing them to `db`. In other words, is there an `SQL` operation that would append new `data.frame`s directly to `table_id`?

Comment: I'd suggest taking your data from wide to long format first... So let's say your data has id, col1, col2, col3. If you change it such that it's like id, feature, value... so that the first row is like id1, col1, value1. The features column is now your separate columns. Then the db schema is the same even if your dataframes have different numbers of columns.

Comment: @cory this will result in very bad performance and force conversion of different data types to string or some variant type. The key-value schema is considered a bad table design. Actually, the OP should *not* try to stuff different frames in the same table. Different tables should be used and in fact, it would be far better to design the tables in advance and add the proper indexes.